# How can I convert $\TeX$ image to Wolfram expression via MathPix

Tags: web-access

*Mathpix* is a tool which can covert $\TeX$ image to $\TeX$ expression, they also say they can return a string which is compatible with the Wolfram Alpha engine if possible.

I found their documentation and did such an attempt:

doc: https://docs.mathpix.com/#processing-a-single-image

```
img = Import@"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Mathpix/api-examples/master/images/limit.jpg";
base64 = ExportString[ExportString[img, "JPEG"], "Base64"];
HTTPRequest[
    "https://api.mathpix.com/v3/latex",
    <|
        "Method" -> "POST",
        "Headers" -> {
            "app_id" -> "trial",
            "app_key" -> "34f1a4cea0eaca8540c95908b4dc84ab",
            "Content-type" -> "application/json"
        },
        "Body" -> {
            "src" -> "data:image/jpg;base64," <> base64,
            "format" -> <|"wolfram" -> True|>
        }
    |>
] // URLExecute[#, "RawJSON"]&
```

Then Mathematica kept asking me to input Authentication Require, and no matter what I do with that, it always return:

```
<|
    "error" -> "Invalid credentials",
    "error_info" -> <|
        "id" -> "http_unauthorized",
        "message" -> "Invalid credentials"
    |>
|>
```

I don't know what Authentication Require is, can I avoid jumping out of that verification.

Comment: For https://github.com/oovm/Mathpix, How do you set the key in ```PersistentValue["Mathpix", "Local"]={"$KeyName","$KeyValue"};```? Is "$KeyName" supposed to be replaced with a string representing the keyname? And what is the key name?

Comment: It's the trial key, if you don't set your own key, this will be used by default. This key was valid before, but now it seems to have been cancelled.

Comment: So I'm assuming the App ID and the App Key from our account on the mathpix website get pasted in inside the quotes? https://imgur.com/a/UKpR9EQ

Comment: Or do we on a separate line put ```$KeyName = myusername123 ```

Comment: Also, it seems like running this : ```ResourceFunction["GitHubInstall"]["GalAster", "Mathpix"]``` doesn't provide a Mathpix function. ```? Mathpix``` returns ```Missing["UnknownSymbol", "Mathpix"]```

Answer (score 2):

Try Mathpix API in Mathematica

https://github.com/Moe-Net/Mathpix

Comment: Isn't that created by the very same person who asked the question above? :-)

Comment: This api do not work

Comment: please could you help to undestoodhow itis work